# Proxy_pass vs fastcgi_pass for nginx / php-fpm

Tags: proxy, php, nginx, reverse-proxy

What is the difference between a nginx reverse proxy server with apache/nginx-php backend with proxy_pass, and a nginx server in the front with fastcgi_pass to backends with only php-fpm. Can both usages also not load balance? And with the latter, should there be less overhead as there is no 2nd server involved?

I am getting started with nginx and was wondering how the two are supposed to be used?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/1041989/proxy-pass-vs-fastcgi-pass